# Problems with "autorelease"

Tags: objective-c, release

I have a problem with "autorelease", look my code: Then in "autorelease" take a 2 message error:

-'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

AND:

ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
//code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 25;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
                           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
                           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];      
         if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ***autorelease***];

    } 


    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rental Property:%d", indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Rental Property %d", indexPath.row);
    return cell;    return cell;
}
```

Someone can help?

Thx!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the call to `-autorelease`. You don't need it in ARC mode.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not your code, but a third party library that you copied and pasted, you should turn off ARC specifically for the implementation file under Targets-> Build Phases -> Compile Sources and under the complier flags for the offending file type in

> -fno-objc-arc

Comment: was this the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use autorelease when using ARC. ARC stands for "Automatic Reference Counting," and it handles the retaining and releasing of objects automatically.